# Can someone distinguish between RDD Lineage and a DAG (Direct Acyclic Graph)?

Tags: apache-spark, directed-acyclic-graphs

Can someone clarify what is the difference & similarities between RDD Lineage & DAG (Direct Acyclic graphs)?

Comment: The body and contents of the question appear to be different?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**DAG** (direct acyclic graph) is the representation of the way Spark will execute your program - each vertex on that graph is a separate operation and edges represent dependencies of each operation. Your program (thus DAG that represents it) may operate on multiple entities (RDDs, Dataframes, etc). **RDD Lineage** is just a portion of a DAG (one or more operations) that lead to the creation of that particular RDD.

So, one DAG (one Spark program) might create multiple RDDs, and each RDD will have its lineage (i.e that path in your DAG that lead to that RDD). If some partitions of your RDD got corrupted or lost, then Spark may rerun that part of the DAG that leads to the creation of those partitions.

If the sole purpose of your Spark program is to create only one RDD and it's the last step, then the whole DAG is a lineage of that RDD.

You can find out more here - https://data-flair.training/blogs/rdd-lineage/

Comment: nice explanation !   Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In Simple Words
Lineage: Logical plan to derive one RDD from other, it is the result of a transformation.
DAG: Physical plan which will be executed as a result of an action on RDD
https://ch-nabarun.medium.com/few-spark-concepts-35d2aa026e28

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we create a dataframe or Spark SQL or a HIVE query, spark will

i. Generate an Unresolved Logical Plan*.

ii. Then it will apply Analysis rules and Schema catalog to convert into a Resolved Logical Plan.

What’s happening here? Understand the source of the datasets and types of the columns.

iii. The Optimization rules will finally create an Optimized Logical Plan.

The above mentioned 3 steps fall under Catalyst Optimizer which is responsible to optimize the logical plan.

Here, Logical plan is nothing but Lineage. Whenever an action is called, this lineage will be converted into a DAG, basically a Physical plan.